# There was an error while trying to write to `/opt/wpscan/.bundle/config`. It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu-14.04

Hello I use a google cloud instance to run my codes,
`techonepl@instance-1:/opt/wpscan$ sudo gem install bundler && bundle install --without test
Fetching: bundler-1.14.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.14.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.14.6
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.14.6
Done installing documentation for bundler after 7 seconds
1 gem installed
There was an error while trying to write to`/opt/wpscan/.bundle/config`. It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.`
Even if I am running it using sudo, what else I need to grant?
System info: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty
2GB Ram
Runs on Google Cloud.
I was trying to install "wpscan"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed it by
`curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
rvm install 2.2.3
rvm use 2.2.3 --default
echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc
gem install bundler`

And `sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/wpscan/.bundle`

Works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/wpscan/.bundle
```

Comment: Typo, mate, chmod, it is, sorry to point out a mistake outta there, wouldn't root work?

Comment: I get again a error, fixed about the permissions, but
`techonepl@instance-1:/opt/wpscan$ ruby2.4 wpscan.rb --update
Could not find gem 'typhoeus (>= 1.1.2)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.`

Comment: you need other dependent gem, run `bundle install` in your project

Comment: Again
`techonepl@instance-1:/opt/wpscan$ gem install ffi -v '1.9.18'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.18
1 gem installed
techonepl@instance-1:/opt/wpscan$ ruby2.4 wpscan.rb --update
Could not find ffi-1.9.18 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.`
Its installed even

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variable `BUNDLE_PATH` to a folder the user has permission to write into, e.g.

```
export BUNDLE_PATH=$HOME/.bundle/
```

See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/6272#issuecomment-1381683835).