# fail ruby bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

adan@adan-HP-1000-Notebook-PC:~/wpscan$ sudo gem install bundler && bundle install --without test
Fetching: bundler-1.15.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.15.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.15.1
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.15.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 10 seconds
1 gem installed
There was an error while trying to write to `/home/adan/wpscan/.bundle/config`.
It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.

i don't know why, this problem always follow me

Comment: what is your operating system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There was an error while trying to write to \`/opt/wpscan/.bundle/config\`. It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942545/there-was-an-error-while-trying-to-write-to-opt-wpscan-bundle-config-it-is)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: never install gems with sudo. To fix this for the future try uninstalling all gems / ruby, install rvm or rbenv them create a gemset for specific project and then install gems with bundle install. This error will most likely follow You a while if You don't repair it.

sudo gem install bundler && sudo bundle install

This probably would help, just for now.