# How to solve Bundler::PermissionError There was an error while trying to write to... on windows

Tags: ruby, windows

While running `bundle install` on windows I get the following error unless I run from an elevated prompt.

```
Bundler::PermissionError There was an error while trying to write to < path > It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path
```

While running the install from an elevated prompt works around the issue, it sounds like a huge security risk for the OS and I'd like to be able to install projects without running into the error.
While there are similar posts, they are all targeting linux or mac as far as I can tell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There was an error while trying to write to \`/opt/wpscan/.bundle/config\`. It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942545/there-was-an-error-while-trying-to-write-to-opt-wpscan-bundle-config-it-is)

Comment: Duplicate of [42942545](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942545/there-was-an-error-while-trying-to-write-to-opt-wpscan-bundle-config-it-is/)

Comment: The question you linked is on linux, this one is for windows for the simple reason the paths are different on both platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your environment `export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem` and the problem seams to be solved!
By adding this, `bundle` will install the downloaded gems under `$HOME/.gem`.

Add it to your bash configuration file:

```
echo `export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem` >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

Found on [GitHub](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1267#issuecomment-730126503)

Answer (score 0):

Granting `Modify` and `Write` permissions to the following paths for the `MachineName\Users` group solved the issue. Alternatively you could change the owner from the administrators group to your current user or only grant that permission to your current user.

- C:\Ruby32-x64\lib\ruby\gems\ruby-version\cache
- C:\Ruby32-x64\lib\ruby\gems\ruby-version\extensions
- C:\Ruby32-x64\lib\ruby\gems\ruby-version\specifications
- C:\Ruby32-x64\lib\ruby\gems\ruby-version\gems
- C:\Ruby32-x64\bin